# Getting rest_user_cannot_view with bearer authentication, customer user and using JWT Plugin

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

When I try to login by Customer (role) using the token by JWT Plugin using a Custumer user I

When I get token by JWT Plugin using username and pwd of a administrator (role) I can get full access of every woocommerce api. But if I get token by customer (role) I just have access to wordpress apis, if I try to get access, for example, domain/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/xxx, it is not been allowed. Response:

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
"message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
"data": {
    "status": 403
}
```

}

Comment: Found any solution?